# Discrete math(Pascal triangle)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

What is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion of $(5x^2 +3)^{14}$

Leave answer as an expression rather than number.

Do I have to expand using the pascal triangle 10 times or is there a formula cos they said leave it as a mathematical expression?

Comment: Remember the binomial theorem?

Comment: Do you know how to create the 10th row of Pascal's triangle without doing all the rows before it?

Comment: I believe this was already asked earlier today: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261462/computing-the-coefficient-in-a-large-polynomial/

Comment: Wasn't this asked just some hours ago?  Did that question get deleted?

Comment: Homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k} = \\ = \binom{n}{0}x^0y^n + \binom{n}{1}x^1y^{n-1} + \binom{n}{2}x^2y^{n-2} + \dots + \binom{n}{n}x^ny^0$$
where $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$